# I have list contains 7000 item, and I need to show latest 10 items on the home page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have list contains 7000 item, and I need to show latest 10 items on the home page.

I created new view with the following settings, and I Added to the home page, I noticed that the home page become slower than before.

[image]

should I consider the **SharePoint list threshold** in my implementation? and what I should do to make my page performance better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use indexed columns to improve performance.

**UPDATE**

I am going to make some assumptions in answering your question.

1. You are the administrator
2. List View Threshold is 5000 for normal users
3. List View Threshold is 20000 for administrators
4. You created a view to get latest 10 items (sorted on `Created` field) without applying any other filter to the view.

If you index the `Created` column and specify it in the Sort section, apply item limit to 10 and don't specify any filter, you would expect it to work for normal users. However, it won't work as the number of items returned are still beyond 5000 limit. But if you repeat the same procedure with out of the box ID field it does work.

Suppose, you create a view and apply a filter on non indexed column and the view returns 4000 items and total number of items in a list is 7000. The normal users will get throttling exception. This is because the view will try to scan all items (7000) in the list and then apply the filter. However, if the field is indexed, it will only scan 4000 items and users won't see throttling exception.

In nutshell, both indexed columns and filters should be used together to improve the performance.

Check this article for detailed guidance:
http://shareden.blogspot.in/2012/07/experimenting-with-large-sharepoint.html

Comment: Thank you, can you provide me with more details? please, is "limit the total number ..." not enough to enhance the performance?, and regarding Indexed columns: should I add "Created" column to Indexed columns?

Comment: Limiting the items in view will help but creating an index on created field will improve it further.

Comment: can you explain how  "limiting the items in view will help" with "SharePoint list threshold"? please, and is there any reference on that?.

Comment: Check this http://www.future-processing.pl/blog/sharepoint/

Answer (score 1):

To create a view:

Go to the list or library where you want to create a view, click the List or Library tab, and then click Create View.

NOTE:  If Create View is disabled, you don’t have the permissions to create a view. For information about the permissions you need to create personal and public views, see the Settings for views section below.

[image]

The SharePoint Library Create view  button on ribbon.

On the Settings page, choose a view type. For information on each type, see Types of views you can choose below.

In the View Name box, type the name for your view. Select Make this the default view if you want to make this the default view for the list or library. Only a public view can be the default view for a list or library.

[image]

Create View Settings page
In the Audience section, under View Audience, select Create a Personal view or Create a Public view. Create a personal view when you want a view just for yourself. Create a public view when you want everyone who uses the list to see it.

NOTE:  If Create a Public View is disabled, you don’t have the permissions to create a public view for this list or library.

In the Columns section, select the columns that you want in the view and clear the columns that you don’t want to appear. Next to the column numbers, select the order that you want to columns to appear in the view.

Configure the other settings for your view, such as Sort and Filter, and click OK at the bottom of the page. For descriptions of all of the settings you can choose, see Settings for views below.

for information click this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9#bkmk_237324407