# Sharepoint List Threshold even when returning less then 5000 records

Tags: web-services, caml-query, list-view-threshold, threshold

I work for a company that creates software that interfaces with Sharepoint using Web Services.  We have run into an issue at a few clients where we are hitting the threshold limit on document libraries that contain records greater then 5000, even though our query is only returning a few records.  It was my understanding that you would only hit the limit if your query or view returned 5000 or more records.

Here's an example of a request using the lists.asmx web service.

```
var libID = "{97769110-C075-4BB8-93F3-8FD97A1C5AEB}";
var viewName = null;
var xnodeQuery = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"BATCH_NO\" /><Value Type=\"Text\">123456ABC12345</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Created\" Ascending=\"False\" /></OrderBy></Query>";
var xnodeViewFields = "<ViewFields Properties=\"True\" />";
var xnodeQueryOptions = "<QueryOptions><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc><ViewAttributes Scope=\"Recursive\" /></QueryOptions>"
var xListItems = listService.GetListItems(libID, viewName, xnodeQuery, xnodeViewFields, "", xnodeQueryOptions, "");
```

Comment: Can you post the code which hits the threshold limit?

Comment: What are the indexed columns ? Your filter columns need to be indexed, even if it returns less 5000 items.

Comment: Ok well i wasn't aware i needed to create an index even if i'm returning less then 5000 records!!!

Comment: You don't have to if you are not going to go over 5k. Indexing is good regardless, anything that can help performance.

Comment: Well ok now i'm confused ... Will you hit the threshold limit on a list that contains no index's and has over 5000 records if you are returning less then 5000 records?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a row limit on your query? SharePoint doesn't know how many items your query will return until it executes it, so I wouldn't be surprised if it rejects this query immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from improving performance, indexing may help in averting the list throttling issues if applied properly.

> Suppose, you create a view and apply a filter on non indexed column
>   and the view returns 4000 items and total number of items in a list is
>   7000. Normal users with non admin access will get throttling exception. This is because the view will try to scan all items (7000) in the list and then apply
>   the filter. However, if the field is indexed, it will only scan 4000
>   items and users won't see throttling exception.

See this for more information: [I have list contains 7000 item, and I need to show latest 10 items on the home page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135197/i-have-list-contains-7000-item-and-i-need-to-show-latest-10-items-on-the-home-p/135198#135198)